# Generate Distinct random numbers

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to generate 100 distinct random numbers between 0 to 800 and repeat the random number generation 10 times then separate the numbers using a comma but i'm having a problem. In this example i'm using a 2D array to achieve this but I don't seem to get it working.

```
int main(void)
{
  int table[10][10];
  int i;
  int nSize = sizeof(table)/sizeof(int);

  for (i = 0; i < nSize; i++)
  {
     for (j = 0; j < nSize; j++)
        printf("%d,",table[i][j] = rand() % 800);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

The output is supposed to look something similar to the following:

```
1, 3, 500, 400, 322, ...
2, 5, 200, 321, 212, ...
500, 433, 421, 354, 545, ...
..
..
..
..
..
..
500, 321, 314, 434, 343, ...
```

The above is an example and not the actual values.

Comment: In your example of the output, 500 is not distinct but the title says you want distinct numbers

Comment: If they're distinct, they're not really random.

Comment: Note that `nSize` is 100, so you're indexing into a 10x10 table as if it was a 100x100 table.  This is not going to be happy.  You could use the standard `int nSize = sizeof(table) / sizeof(table[0])`;` to get the number `10` (or, in this case, `int nSize = sizeof(table[0]) / sizeof(table[0][0]);`).  If the matrix were not square, you could use both expressions assigned to different variables.  Note that the first expression works regardless of the type of the table elements.

Answer (score 1):

1. One of the dimensions of `table` should be 100, since you have 100 random numbers.
2. In the inner loop, you should either make sure the random number has not already been generated, or (more complex and more efficient) use some kind of shuffling algorithm.
3. Does rand() % 800 produce a number between 0 and 800?

Comment: yes! rand % 800 produces a number between 0 and 800

Comment: @GeekyCoder: it produces a number in the range `[0,800)` or `0 <= x < 800`.  It never generates 800.  That may be what you're after.

Comment: @GeekyCoder You might also want to be aware that using the modulus operator to give you a number between 0 and n may not give you a uniform distribution of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define ROW 10
#define COL 10
int array[ROW][COL];
for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
        array[i][j] = rand() % 801; // if rand() % 800, then it generate 0 - 799, never 800
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the `printf("\n")` into the outer for loop and you don't have to use an array:

```
int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            printf("%s%d", j > 0 ? "," : "", rand() % 800);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Note: this will generate numbers between 0 and 799.